# Please tell me how to use two delivery protocols at the same time with one-simulator

Tags: dtn, one-simulator

What should I do if I want to change the delivery protocol depending on the node such as SpW to the node that is fixed to Epidemic as the node that runs with one-simulator?thank you.

Comment: Hi. Have you tried to configure two distinct routing groups?

Answer (score 0):

You can't currently change the routing protocol on the fly but you can set the routing module per node group in the configuration for the duration of the simulation. But note that not all routing modules are compatible with each other (e.g., MaxProp works only with other MaxProp routers).